# Stop the effect of %matplotlib notebook in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic, python-magic

I used the magic commands `%matplotlib notebook` at some ceil in my notebook to animate some scatter plots.

 However, after that ceil, I want to remove the effect of this magic command.

 Anyone has any idea of how to do this?

Comment: You can swap to a different backend, like `%matplotlib inline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the interactive mode off via [`plt.ioff()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ioff.html)